# JSP Validator is not appearing in my Properties

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

On my old computer, Eclipse would validate my JSP files. With the new installation, it no longer does and there is not an option to apply a JSP validator under Project->Properties->Validation. Am I missing a configuration, a plugin, or a package? Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Eclipse Version? It exists on Eclipse Helios.

Comment: @The Elite: the one for Java EE, yes. It by the way already existed since the version for J2EE 1.2 almost a decade ago.

Comment: @BalusC, I see I've posted the same answer as you, so much for me being slow today. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion is that you don't have [Eclipse for Java EE developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jee.php) installed. You just have Eclipse for Java Developers.

You will need Web Tools which contains JSP validators. Just check the comparisons of Eclipse [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php).

Answer (score 0):

You need [Eclipse for Java **EE** developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr1), not "just" [Eclipse for Java developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliossr1).

Instead of redownloading the whole thing, you can also just get the [WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) plugin by *Help > Install New Software*. It contains among others the necessary tools for JSP development.